# Bash: Filter gz file by value in specific column

Tags: linux, bash

As a title, I have a very large .csv.gz file and I am trying to filter the rows by a specific value in one of the columns here, for example (col3=="Female")

**Raw:**

```
Yes Yes Female Male
Yes No Male Female
No No Female Female
```

**output wanted:**

```
Yes Yes Female Male
No No Female Female
```

Tried:

```
gzcat file.csv.gz | awk '$3==Female {print}'
```

But it really not filter anything at all.

Can anyone help here?
Many thanks.

Comment: In your example `Female` is a variable.

Comment: Behavior is 100% identical whether it's `gzcat file.csv.gz | awk` or `<file.csv awk`. And if there's no difference, [mcve] rules hold that your question should be simplified to the maximum extent possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
gzcat file.csv.gz | awk '$3=="Female" || $1=="col1"'
```

Output:

```
col1 col2 col3
Yes Yes Female
No No Female
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus for your comment.
I just edited my question, and the now the raw is come without the headers. 
So seems the code above won't work if the header is gone.